# Type hint for a dict gives TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

```
memo: dict[int, int] = {0: 0, 1: 1} # *our base cases*
```

returns the following error:

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: This syntax is currently valid since Python 3.9 added type hints to standard collections

Comment: `from __future__ import annotations`

Comment: @user26742873: To be clear, that solves the problem when the annotation is used directly. But it won't solve pre-defined stuff used for annotations later, e.g. `IntIntDict = dict[int, int]`, so you could later write `memo: IntIntDict = {...}` would fail with or without `from __future__ import annotations`, because creating that alias *must* run actual code (it's not an annotation itself, so it actually gets run, and `dict` pre-3.9 will explode if you try it).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I have upgraded Python so I didn't test that, but that should be true. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I guess you should use `Dict`, e.g.:

```
from typing import Dict

memo: Dict[int, int] = {0: 0, 1: 1}
```

In your case, you were using `dict` which is of type `type`

```
>>> type(dict)
<class 'type'>
>>> type(Dict)
<class 'typing._GenericAlias'>
```

Comment: what's the difference between dict and Dict?

Comment: @RobertLi [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict) is the built-in datatype and [`Dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=dict#typing.Dict) the corresponding type.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist is right. See the difference in the answer

Comment: Since Python 3.9 you can use build-in types in annotations. From typing module:
These types became redundant in Python 3.9 when the corresponding pre-existing classes were enhanced to support []

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
from typing import Dict
mydict = Dict[int, int]

mydict = {0: 0, 1: 1}
```

Result:

```
>>>mydict
{0: 0, 1: 1}
```

If this is what you wanted.